# Can I use multiple parameters when using WHERE in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

(when selecting data from tables in MYSQL database)
something like this:

WHERE some_column = some_value, other_column = other_value

If not, Is there other simple method rather than going into "if loops"

Comment: What's wrong with using `WHERE some_column=some_value AND other_column=other_value`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `if` is not a loop and there is nothing wrong in them anyway. most of time you have to use `if` statements to create a dynamical mysql query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just separate them with `AND`s:

```
WHERE some_column=some_value AND other_column=other_value
```

Comment: You can also use OR depending on the logical result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE some_column = some_value AND other_column = other_value
```